# Black Background in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am working on a little web application that involves both horizontally flipping and rotating an image using browser-specific css.  In any browser other than IE, the result is what I want.  In IE, when I use -ms-filter and FlipH along msTransform and rotate, I get a black background in the shape of a square around the image (but the transformation is still exactly how I want it).  Does anybody have any experience fixing this problem?  Also, if somebody has access to a microsoft employee, could you convey my hatred towards him/her.

Example of the HTML causing me the problem:

```
<img src="test.png" style="filter: FlipH; -ms-transform: rotate(25deg);">
```

Comment: which IE version are you using?

Comment: The black you are seeing is the alpha transparency layer of the PNG being converted into black.  From my experience, IE + transparent PNG images + animation does not work very well.

Comment: IE9 but some backwards compatibility would be nice.  Funny, I know.